# how to display image from database

Tags: php, mysql

i am try to retrieve image and content  from database  but content is showing but image is not show please any one help me how to do.i am able to insert image and content.  you can see my website http://prawahindia.com/development/blogdisplay.php

```
   //this is display code
 <?php
    include('connects.php');
    $select_posts = "select * from testblob";
     $run_posts = mysql_query($select_posts); 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_posts))
   {
    echo '<p class="games_image_result"><img src="'.$row->image.'" width="175"  height="200" />';
      echo '<p class="games_content_result">' .$_content = $row['body'];

     }
   ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html>
   <head><title>File Upload To Database</title></head>
  <body>
  <h2>Please Write a comment</h2>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo    htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999" />
   <div><input name="userfile" type="file" /></div>
    <div><textarea name="body"  style="width:200px; height:100px;"></textarea></div>
   <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    </form>

  </body></html>
 <?php

 if(!isset($_FILES['userfile']))
    {
     echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
   }
  else
    {
     try    {
    upload();

    echo '<p>Thank you for submitting</p>';
    }
   catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo '<h4>'.$e->getMessage().'</h4>';
    }
   }
  ?>

   <?php

   function upload(){

       if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) && getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) != false)
    {

   $size = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

$type = $size['mime'];
$imgfp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$size = $size[3];
$name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$maxsize = 99999999;
$body=$_POST['body'];

if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize )
    {

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=abc", 'root', 'root');

            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);            
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO testblob (image_type ,image, image_size, image_name,body) VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?, ?)");


    $stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $body);


    $stmt->execute();
    }
else
    {

    throw new Exception("File Size Error");
    }
   }
else
  {

  throw new Exception("Unsupported Image Format!");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you even inspect the resulting HTML code of your webpage? Just taking a look at the first picture would show you what's wrong: `<img src="<?php echo $row->image; ?>;" width="175" height="200">`. Take a look at the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) on how to concatenate strings and variables.

Comment: If you store the image directly in the database you can't output it just into the HTML. You have to create a separate PHP script that reads the image from the database and outputs it. Then you can place a link to that script into the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
echo '<p class="games_image_result"><img src="<?php echo $row->image; ?>" width="175"  height="200" />';
```

to

```
echo '<p class="games_image_result"><img src="' . $row->image . '" width="175"  height="200" />';
```

**EDIT**: After your question edit...

You are storing blob, raw data into database. And in order to show picture on your page you need to enter base64 encoded data into src of your image tag.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '"/>';
```

Comment: Then gave us more info how your image is stored in the DB. If it's a blob, look at EquinoxMatt's answer.

Comment: how to set size of image when use echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . width=60px height=60px '"/>'; getting error

Comment: `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" width="60" height="60" />';`

Comment: you should really look at the source of your rendered page first. This kind of errors are easy to spot.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_posts))
   {?>
 <p class="games_image_result"><img src="<?php echo $row->image; ?>" width="175"  height="200" />';
<p class="games_content_result"><?php echo $row['body'];?>

<?php  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have stored your image as a blob, you need to use base64:

```
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode($row['image']) ?>"/>
```

No idea why your trying to use $row->image when your using an array.

If you are simply storing the path you need to change from:

```
    <img src="<?php echo $row->image; ?>" width="175"  height="200" />';
```

to:

```
    <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" width="175"  height="200" />';
```

EDIT 2:

Your server config is fine, your code is wrong all over the place. You don't seem to understand basic string syntax.  Don't use php to print your HTML, it is unreadable... try this:

```
    <?php
    include('connects.php');
    $select_posts = "select * from testblob";
    $run_posts = mysql_query($select_posts);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_posts))
    { ?>
<p class="games_image_result"><img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" width="175"  height="200" />
<p class="games_content_result"><?php echo $_content = $row['body']; }
    ?>
```